# Criar uma label ao ler os dados dum ficheiro

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, label

Eu estou a tentar criar um botao que, usando a informaçao depositada em 3 ficheiros (labelName, LabelX, LabelY), crie um numero de labels conforme o numero de entradas.

Ou seja, se eu tiver 1 entrada em cada ficheiro (um nome no LabelName, um numero no LabelX, outro numero no LabelY) irá criar uma label com o nome referido nas posiçoes Top e Left apontados nos ficheiros LabelX e LabelY respetivamente.

Neste momento o problema é que nao sei como fazer com que o meu ciclo passe da primeira entrada e assim o que eu tenho é uma repetiçao dos primeiros valores criando multiplas vezes a primeira label baseado [nestes dados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZH9U.png) (na foto marcados a azul).

O meu codigo é o seguinte:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       for (int i = 0; i < labelList.Count(); i++)
       {
                Label l = new Label();
               //NOTA: tentativa anterior = *exemplo_abaixo*
                
                TextReader oner = new StreamReader("labelName.txt");
                string ltext = oner.ReadLine();
                
                TextReader twor = new StreamReader("labelX.txt");
                string labelLeft = twor.ReadLine();

                TextReader threer = new StreamReader("labelY.txt");
                string labelTop = threer.ReadLine();


                l.Text = ltext;
                l.Left = Convert.ToInt32(labelLeft);
                l.Top = Convert.ToInt32(labelTop);

                Controls.Add(l);
                ControlExtension.Draggable(l, true);

                oner.Close();
                twor.Close();
                threer.Close();

        }
  }
```

Só queria compreender como faço para o meu ciclo passar do primeiro valor de cada ficheiro e criar o resto das labels.

Obrigado.

Comment: Tens que guardar os valores fora do for depois em cada execução do for incrementas o valor que está guardado, por exemplo guardas int ValorTop=0; depois a cada ciclo ValorTop+=ValorQueQueresDescerALabelSeguinte;

Comment: Não entendi... você lê sempre os mesmos arquivos e espera receber valores diferentes?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo nao, eu quero os diferentes valores no ficheiro mas apenas consigo o primeiro valor de cada ficheiro em vez de os que tenho em cada linha

Comment: Não seria por que você está sempre lendo a primeira linha? Ao ver o seu código me parece que há algumas falhas na lógica e estrutura, o que é `labelList.Count()`? O que acontece se houver mais labels na lista no que coordenadas nos arquivos? Por que três arquivos, um com cada tipo de informação?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo labelList.Count() foi usada para fazer contagem do numero de labels que foram para o ficheiro, é apenas usada com esse efeito como uma maneira de evitar ter labels a mais ou a menos. Cada uma dessas labels terá coordenadas Top e Left e foram colocadas cada uma na sua lista pela mesma razão - nao ter valores a mais ou a menos (ou pelo menos para tentar). Dessa maneira o primeiro dado de cada lista corresponde ao dado na mesma posiçao noutra lista.

Podia ser menos complicado? Possivelmente. Mas eu nao sou muito experiente em c# e vou aprendendo á medida que faço...

Comment: O que importa são as linhas que estão registradas nos arquivos?

Comment: sim. O `labelList.Count()` é apenas uma variavel para o ciclo ter um fim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é armazernar todas as informações da label em um único arquivo, separando os atributos por `;`. Se o que importa são as informações que foram persistidas, não a necessidade de per outro loop para isso

**labelList.txt**

```
label1;774;592
192.168.1.156;600;222
PCZ;607;284
```

E no código basta ler esse arquivo montando os seus controles

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (TextReader leitor = new StreamReader("labelList.txt"))
    {
        string linha;
        while ((linha = leitor.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var linhaDados = linha.Split(';');

            Label label = new Label
            {
                Text = linhaDados[0],
                Left = Convert.ToInt32(linhaDados[1]),
                Top = Convert.ToInt32(linhaDados[2])
            };

            Controls.Add(label);
            ControlExtension.Draggable(label, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mako, veja se você consegue entender o código acima e se ele atende a sua necessidade.

Comment: Pelo que eu consigo compreender eu ja usei os metodos que apresenta em cima durante a minha aprendizagem, no entanto eu nao conhecia o metodo `Split` que mostra acima ainda. Apenas tive que adaptar o codigo para inserir no ficheiro para apenas inserir num ficheiro e funciona sem problema. 

Obrigado!